# Failed to Find "it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11" android studio dependencies error

Tags: android

I applied following library dependencies,In my android studio take only com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+ like that and all google dependencies.If i apply private library dependencies like following

```
Failed to find:it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11![Failed to find library dependencies in build.gradle android studio][1] 

     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
     compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
     compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
     compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
     compile 'com.telly:mrvector:0.2.0'
     compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
     compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
     compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.1.0'
     compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
     compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
     compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
     compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0'

}

Failed to find library dependencies in build.gradle android studio.
```

I researched so many times and tried so many ways.but i can't find solutions.i don't know this is a studio gradle problems or my company blocked some firewalls certificate for security.I want to solutions urgent.please somebody solve this problem and help for me.currently i have used jar files only.If i used jar files through libs folder then what is diffrent between eclipse and android studio/

Comment: check if you have marked offline work or what

Answer (score 0):

Try sync gradle again and check if you can link to this page: 
https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/neokree/MaterialTabs/maven-metadata.xml

If you can't, if might be the firewall problem.

And some dependencies might out of date.

I help you to sync the latest version using [andle](https://github.com/Jintin/andle)

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7: 21.0.+ -> 23.1.0
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7: 21.0.+ -> 23.1.0
com.mcxiaoke.volley:library: 1.0.+ -> 1.0.19
jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators: 1.1.0 -> 2.0.1
com.daimajia.easing:library: 1.0.1 -> 1.0.2
com.android.support:gridlayout-v7: 22.0.0 -> 23.1.0
```